# Problem with the set() function from GeoFirestore

Tags: node.js, firebase, geofirestore

I want to use the `set(...)` function, but Firebase-Log says that this function is not available.

The Firebase-Cloud-Function Log:

"TypeError: GeoPostLocations.set is not a function
at database.collection.doc.collection.doc.set.then.result"

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
var admin = require('firebase-admin');
var serviceAccount = require('./serviceAccountKey.json');

var GeoFirestore = require('geofirestore').GeoFirestore;
const database = admin.firestore();
const geofirestore = new GeoFirestore(database);
const GeoPostLocations = geofirestore.collection('PostLocations');
```

In my function, I execute the following code:

```
return GeoPostLocations.set("DummyIDForTest", [50.312312312, 5.4302434234]]).then(result => {
        console.log(result);
        return 0;
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
        return 1;
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it looks like you've been doing a bit of your code in the syntax of version 2 of `geofirestore`, but we're now on v3 and things should look more like `firestore`, so what does that mean for you?

Firstly, set isn't a function available to collections, but it is available to documents, so you'll wanna do this:

```
return GeoPostLocations.doc('DummyIDForTest').set({
    coordinates: new firebase.firestore.GeoPoint(50.312312312, 5.4302434234)
}).then(result => {
    console.log(result);
    return 0;
}).catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
    return 1;
});
```

Please note that you have to set an object, not coordinates in an array (this isn't `geofire`). [I've included a link to the relevant docs](https://geofirestore.com/classes/_geodocumentreference_.geodocumentreference.html#set).